# Can we display variable values in 'PROPERTY OVERRIDES' Section of execution report in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis

Is it possible to display variable values in 'PROPERTY OVERRIDES' Section of execution report in SSIS?

I have tried with the script task in the SSIS package but not getting desired output.
Thanks in Advance